# .NET session state variables

Tags: .net, session, state

Is there any special means to store the controls in the Sessions? I was trying to store panel control with couple of text boxes in it. For some reason when I extract the Panel back from Session, It shows empty -( wondering whats going on with Panel?

BTW, whats the best way to debug the ASPX script( not C# coding) ?

Comment: code in aspx is not scripting but compiled code as anything else

Answer (score 0):

Read the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) to see why controls can't be stored in session. Pages are very short-lived, and when they are disposed, so are their controls. Trying to access them after disposal will lead to errors.

You should be storing just the data in your session variables, not the controls themselves.

Comment: I think I am still not clear about sessions. Whats the difference between string object and control object  when I am able to store string object in a session and why not the same case with any control object. I mean string object should also die when the page is disposed ? Or Am I missing something ?